# Bash error: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, while-loop

I wrote a really simple file explorer using ls with a shell script. I used a while loop to make the script run forever (until Ctrl+C), but the while loop doesn't seem to work. I get this error

```
./fileexplorer: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./fileexplorer: line 5: `done'`
```

My code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l $1
while :
    browse()
done

function browse()
{
    read file;
    if [ -f $file ]
        if test -e $file
            echo "Starting $file with nano."
            echo "Press a key to open the file."
            pause
            nano $file
    if test -d $file
        ls -l $file
}
```

Comment: paste your code in http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script should work ..

```
#!/bin/bash

function browse()
{
    read file;
    if [ -f $file ]
    then
        if [ -e $file ]
        then
            echo "Starting $file with nano."
            echo "Press a key to open the file."
            sleep 2
            nano $file
        fi
    fi
    if [ -d $file ]
    then
        ls -l $file
     fi
}

ls -l $1

while true;do
browse
done
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct syntax, you need something like:

```
while CONDITION ; do
    ACTION
done
```

Without the `do`, the `done` is indeed unexpected. In addition, your `if` statements should be of the form:

```
if CONDITION ; then
    ACTION
fi
```

The `bash` man page shows the correct forms in more detail:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
while list-1; do list-2; done
```

Keep in mind those shown above are my preferred form, with the `do/then` on the same line as the `while/if`. You can also leave off the `;` and move the `do/then` on to the next line but I consider that unnecessarily wasteful of screen real estate.

Comment: I fixed it but it still gives the same error. I changed it to "while True; do".